# How to get around "sys.exit()" in python nosetest?

Tags: python, mocking, nose

It seems that python nosetest will quit when encountered `sys.exit()`, and mocking of this builtin doesn't work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can try catching the [SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) exception. It is raised when someone calls `sys.exit()`.

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
  myFunctionThatSometimesCallsSysExit()
```

Comment: with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
         myFunction()

Answer (score 9):

If you're using `mock` to patch `sys.exit`, you may be patching it incorrectly.

This small test works fine for me:

```
import sys
from mock import patch

def myfunction():
    sys.exit(1)

def test_myfunction():
    with patch('foo.sys.exit') as exit_mock:
        myfunction()
        assert exit_mock.called
```

invoked with:

```
nosetests foo.py
```

outputs:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: Problem with this is that whilst the mock will be called, it won't stop execution, any instructions after the exit will be called.  I.E. if you are exiting because of an error state, the test would carry on to attempt to run potentially broken code.

Answer (score 7):

```
import sys
sys.exit = lambda *x: None
```

Keep in mind that programs may reasonably expect not to continue after `sys.exit()`, so patching it out might not actually help...

Comment: Not necessarily. I use sys.exit() to daemonize my server.

Answer (score 7):

This is an example in the `unittest` framework.

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
    my_function_that_uses_sys_exit()
self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, expected_return_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

From this article on [medium](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/testing-sys-exit-with-pytest-10c6e5f7726f):

```
def test_exit(mymodule):
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as pytest_wrapped_e:
            mymodule.will_exit_somewhere_down_the_stack()
    assert pytest_wrapped_e.type == SystemExit
    assert pytest_wrapped_e.value.code == 42
```